# Send message from server at specific time in php?

Tags: php

Is there any way to send mail at specific time in php?

Please give me hint for that file. I forget to that file which is used to send mail to specific time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to schedule the execution of a PHP script on the server side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194857/how-to-schedule-the-execution-of-a-php-script-on-the-server-side)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use cron.php
this is file name i think you forget that name 
right?

Answer (score 2):

For that you should use [a cron job.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) Cron may be used to launch scripts of any sort (in your case a phpscript).
The usage is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Look up CRON jobs. A CRON job runs a specific php file at a certain time. Other than that there's no way to schedule an email in PHP (afaik).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this with only PHP. You would need to run a cron which would then run the specific PHP script.  If you want to send the mail at the same time each day, then you would run the cron at that time each day and the PHP script would then send your email.

Answer (score 0):

Note that cron jobs can be easily configured at your Cpanel ( if you have one )