# PHP Scheduled Task Security

Tags: php, security, iis-7.5, scheduled-tasks

To piggyback off of this article, [How to schedule the execution of a PHP script on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194857/how-to-schedule-the-execution-of-a-php-script-on-the-server-side), what concerns should I have for the user account that is selected to run the script?

For example, if I use the administrator account and I need to change the password of the administrator account, what happens to my scripts?  Is there a way to have the scripts run on Windows and not have to worry about user account password changes?  Are there other security concerns by running PHP scripts in this manner that I need to be aware of?

Is there a way to make it run on the local system without needing to be an admin user and call php?

Comment: It depends what your scheduled task does. If it's just executing some standard business logic from your web app on a scheduled basis and it's just touching your app's database (and maybe writing some files somewhere) then you don't need to run as administrator or your login.

Answer (score 0):

Typically scheduled tasks with work if a password is updated, as it links into the user account.

However, its not a good idea to create tasks under random users, rule of thumb is typically organize / create users specifically for a scheduled task.  I know internally for domain accounts, we (at my company) have specific accounts that we use for backups, others for scheduled tasks, etc.

That way you separate logic and security layer (backup user isn't full admin, nor is a task running user capable of say touching databases, etc;)

Comment: Would running it under the "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" user account be a better choice?