# PHP - Scheduling function executions

Tags: php, timer

How can I schedule/trigger function execution in php based on timer expiry and also how can I reset and re-execute my timer?

Comment: I'm implementing a Cache for my Objects and I want to flush this local cache after every 30 mins. What is the best inline method to do so? Are Crons the only answer?

Comment: @AnkitGarg if U use standalone application - it is not matter, but if U use webbased application it's not good. Becase http-server will be busy work 30minutes, and it will be stackoverflowed

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but close enough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194857/how-to-schedule-the-execution-of-a-php-script-on-the-server-side

Comment: @hellsgate I know I can achieve this by a cron job, but is there nothing implicit that can be done. Few things that are coming to my mind are:

1. The trigger executing my flush function will have to know the context in which it was called and thus I need to save some vital information before the trigger triggers the flush function.

2. How to ensure consistency in this case?

Comment: @AnkitGarg: I think the main stumbling block would be the max_execution_time or set_time_limit options as it looks like you want this script to run indefinitely. I honestly don't think a PHP script on its own is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a refresh code, using a timer, that reloads a specific page at a specific time, that does only the things you aked; Or you can read from the database the last time that your job has run (if this time has been stored), and if to much time has passed, just run it again.

Answer (score 0):

According to my requirement, I guess the best bet would be crons only. Triggering timers and saving contextual information like stack, memory etc. would be too much overhead for my application. Thanks for your answers.