# run delete query and delete a record each 24 hours in php and mysql

Tags: php

I have a table named tbl_cartag and in table have temp field after user enter data must be erased after 24 hours.

I want this field to be cleared every 24 hours Information.

This is my query

```
DELETE cartag FROM tbl_cartag WHERE tcartagid=( $_GET['tcartagid'] )
```

I read similar questions , but I did not help

[Remove a row from the database after 24 hours in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045179/remove-a-row-from-the-database-after-24-hours-in-php)

[Deleting Data each 24 hours in Database with PHP and MYSQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653702/deleting-data-each-24-hours-in-database-with-php-and-mysqli)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1194864/3164682

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Linux/Unix (including Mac OSX), create a cron job.

if you are using windows then use event scheduler

it will work

Answer (score 0):

I think this option is better:

```
DELETE 
FROM YOUR-TABLE
WHERE
YOUR-DATE-COLUMN < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate/erase everything from temp table
Then you can run the above query

```
DELETE cartag FROM tbl_cartag WHERE tcartagid=( $_GET['tcartagid'] )
```

also you have to create a cron job for this query.

Or if you want to erase 24 hours data from temp table then you have to add Data time query as mentioned by Syed noman

```
YOUR-DATE-COLUMN < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```